# mod_perl and how to install missing libraries

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess, cpan, mod-perl2

i need your help because I need to migrate a Perl application, which appears to be based on something like a CMS called "Profile Manager Premium 4.0". The problem is, i'm trying to use an .htaccess file in order to configure the mod_perl module without having to resort to reload globally the apache daemon and this way harm everyone using it. The problem is there is a file called "pm.cgi" which appears to be the "entry point" for the application and I can't accomplish it to execute correctly, because in the apache error log appears the following message:

```
[Mon Jul 01 11:01:13 2013] [error] Can't locate data/config/pmpre.cfg in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/rt4/sbin/../local/lib /opt/rt4/sbin/../lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /home/webroot/public_html/group_websites/qpeixe/pm.cgi line 36.\n
```

I managed to install some missing modules using the CPAN command but this "pmpre" module I couldn't (I don't know the exact name of the module in order to fetch this 'pmpre.cfg').

Furthermore, I'm not sure if I need to use mod_perl or mod_perl_2, but since I'm using Apache 2.2, but I found it seems to use mod_perl_2. So this way, I dropped inside the .htaccess file the following contents:

```
  <IfModule mod_perl.c>
   SetHandler perl-script
  PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
  PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
  Options +ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all 
  </IfModule>
```

Anyway, I'm not fluent in Perl anyway, so please, I'm just an Web Developer with PHP/Javascript skills.

Anyway, thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the file it's look for is something locally created. When you find out where it's installed (or re-install it yourself), you'll have to [configure mod_perl to look in that directory](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#Adjusting_C__INC_).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the directions you pointed me to follow. After tried the alternatives described in the documentation and using the PerlSwitches directive, I switched the module from mod_perl to mod_cgi, and after everything, the application was using mod_cgi instead of mod_perl ! And I was thinking that every Web perl-based application used mod_perl ! After all, that's not true !